# Convert from PyQt5 to PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

Hey brothers and sisters, I just wondered if anyone could help me convert this program to **PyQt4**. I did my best however I couldn't ;,). It is a basic program for displaying **Real Time text** on the UI.

Here is the program:

```
import sys
import time
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
 
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            number = random.randint(1, 1000)
            self.signal.emit(number)
            time.sleep(1)
 
class WorkerLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
 
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def slot(self, i):
        self.setText(str(i))
 
class UserInterface(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = WorkerLabel(self)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
 
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = UserInterface(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)
 
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        self.workerThread = QtCore.QThread()  # Move the Worker object to the Thread object
        self.workerThread.started.connect(self.worker.run)  # Init worker run() at startup
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.worker.signal.connect(self.ui.label.slot)
        self.workerThread.start()
 
        self.show()
 
if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    gui = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `QtWidgets` to `QtGui`

Comment: Please, consider that StackOverflow is **not** a porting service. You say "I did my best", but, honestly, I cannot see any attempt, you're only providing a fully functional PyQt5 program. And, frankly, considering what takes to port it to PyQt4, I don't think you did anything at all.

Comment: Thank you brother for your kind response, I have an edited version for this program I will ad it now. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in PyQt however I use it to develop a telemetry for Cars, Robots, Small Aircraft. Thanks to **eyllanesc** its solved now and working well. The problem was that **PyQt4 uses QtGui instead of QtWidgets in PyQt5**

Here is the sample code:

```
import sys
import time
import random
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
 
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            number = random.randint(1, 1000)
            self.signal.emit(number)
            time.sleep(1)
 
class WorkerLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
 
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def slot(self, i):
        self.setText(str(i))
 
class UserInterface(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = WorkerLabel(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
 
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = UserInterface(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)
 
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        self.workerThread = QtCore.QThread()  # Move the Worker object to the Thread object
        self.workerThread.started.connect(self.worker.run)  # Init worker run() at startup
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.worker.signal.connect(self.ui.label.slot)
        self.workerThread.start()
 
        self.show()
 
if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    gui = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```